# Connecting to sql database directly in android

Tags: android

I am developing an applciation which requires to connect to sql database server.  I am planning to connect to database directly without using webservice.  Let me know if its possible?

Answer (score 2):

you can directly connect to the sqlite database that is in phone. but you can not directly connect to the remote database like mysql , MSSQL and other database. if you really need to use that database you have to use web service(SOAP or REST), Http request or JSON.

Comment: Hi, I have never tried anything related to MySQL connection on Android, but just being curious. Is is not possible to perform normal MySQL connection setup with mysql library and using codes like `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")` and `DriverManager .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://address/database?user=user&password=pass")`?

Comment: no this is not possible. you have to call the web service first as I above mentioned

Comment: @ Chor WaiChun : within your android code you can not write Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver") and DriverManager .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://address/database?user=user&password=pass")

Answer (score 1):

You can't access remote database server without web services. If you want, you can access internal database (sqlite) without any web services. I have a doubt whether you are asking that. For that this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j-IV87qQ00M) may be helpful for you.